# MacroPDF417 barcode reading FileID from codewords

Tags: barcode

I'm reading the ISO spec for MacroPDF417, FileID field. It says:

> Each codeword in the file ID can have a value between 0 and 899, effectively making the file ID a series of base 900 numbers. Each codeword of the series is transmitted as the 3-digit ASCII representation of its decimal value.

The spec has an example as follows:

> File ID = 17base900 53base900

Which value in codewords is [017] [053].

Can someone explain me, is the fileID value 1753? Or not?

If it's 1753, how to can you read it from codewords? How should the zero before 53 be interpreted? Should it be removed?

Answer (score 0):

No, FileId is not 1753.

As per spec FileId is a series of base 900 numbers, so the above is a series of 017, 053 and not a single number 1753.

We might wright this as 17base900 53base900, this is not equal to 1753 in base 10.

I did not find any tool to read the fileId from a barcode however you can check this value in the codewords using this tool http://online-barcode-reader.inliteresearch.com/default.aspx.

This will be written in codewords as 928nnnnn\017\053 where nnnnn is segment id.

If you are setting the fileId by converting the base 10 number to base 900 numbers then you might convert the codewords back to base 10 numbers to get the originally set value. If you want help in converting to base 10, check this link http://mathbits.com/MathBits/CompSci/Introduction/tobase10.htm.